# Conditions - Linear Combination of 3 Vectors inside a Triangle (Strang P10, 1.1.20)

Tags: vector-spaces

> Under what restrictions on $c, d, e,$ will the combinations $c\mathbf{u} + d\mathbf{v} + e\mathbf{w}$ fill in [ie bridle/rein in] the dashed triangle? To stay in the triangle, one requirement is $c \geq 0 \; \& \; d \geq 0 \; \& \; e \geq 0.$
>
> **Answer:** To fill the triangle keep $c, d, e \geq 0$, and $c + d + e = 1.$
>
> [image]

Could someone please demystify how and why $c + d + e = 1$ ? Where did it even loom from?

---

**Supplement to Revanth Kashyap's Answer:**

How and why:

> ¿ If $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ are coplanar and $k_1\mathbf{u} + k_2\mathbf{v} + k_3\mathbf{w} = 0$, then $ k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 0$ ?

Comment: Think of the linear combination as "weighted average", where $c, d, e$ are weights. In the usual case of average, you'd put $c = d = e = \frac 13$. That would give you the "center" of the triangle. If you want to move the center more toward $u$, you would increase $c$ and decrease $d$ and $e$. When $c$ reaches $1$, you want $d$ and $e$ to be $0$, so that $cu = u$. (Note: the condition $c + d + e = 1$ is sufficient, but you actually can come up with something more sophisticated.)

Answer (score 2):

Shift the Origin to the heads of any of the three vectors, say **w**. The original vectors now become **v**-**w**, **u**-**w**, and $\mathbf 0$(Zero Vector).

Now, in  order that a vector should lie in the triangle thus formed, it should be of the form :

$\lambda$(**v**-**w**)+$\mu$(**u**-**w**), with $\lambda \ge 0$, $\mu$$ \ge$$ 0$ and $\lambda+\mu\le1$

Simplifying the above expression, we get :

$\mu\mathbf{u}$+$\lambda\mathbf{v}$-$(\lambda$+$\mu)\mathbf w$

Reverting to the original Origin, the expression becomes :

$\mu\mathbf{u}$+$\lambda\mathbf{v}$-$(\lambda$+$\mu)\mathbf w$ + $\mathbf w$

i.e., $\mu\mathbf{u}$+$\lambda\mathbf{v}$+$(1-(\lambda$+$\mu))\mathbf w$

Comparing it to $c\mathbf{u} + d\mathbf{v} + e\mathbf{w}$,  we get :

$\mu$ = *c*,  and as $\mu \ge 0$, *c* $\ge 0$

$\lambda$ = *d*,  and as $\lambda \ge 0$, *d* $\ge 0$

$1-(\lambda$+$\mu)$ = *e*, and as $\lambda+\mu\le1$, *e* $\ge 0$

From the above three facts we get, *c* + *d* + *e* = 1 and *c* $\ge 0$, *d* $\ge 0$, and *e* $\ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

consider a vector P = cU+dV+eW as a linear combination of U,V,W

Now if P has to be in the triangle as shown,

vectors UV, VW and PU have to be coplanar

so PU can be expressed as a linear combination of UV and VW

PU = mUV+nVW

(c-1)U + dV + eW = m(V-U)+ n(W-V)

(c+m-1) U + (d+n-m) V + (e-n) W = 0

since U, V , W are non-coplanar, sum of the coefficients in the above equation is 0

and hence c+d+e = 1

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. Could you please respond to my supplement in my OP?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be "Since $U$, $V$ , $W$  are  not coplanar, $c+m-1=d+n-m=e-n=0$, and hence $c+d+e = 1$"

It is because $U$, $V$ , $W$ are coplanar if and only if the equations have
a solution other than α = β = γ$ = 0$ (α$U$ + β$V$ + γ$W = 0$)